# How to do a underbracket with Mathjax?

Tags: support, mathjax

This is the formula that shall be achieved:

[image]

The code from TeX:

```
 \underbracket[0.5pt][5.pt]{78\,255\,300,00}_{10\text{ zählende Ziffern}} \\[10pt]
 0,000\,\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\underbracket[0.5pt][5.pt]{420\,800}_{6\text{zählende Ziffern}}
```

With Mathjax it does not work, obviously `underbracket` is not available.

If you propose a solution, please try to focus on the basic mathjax, not plugins. Thank you for your help.

Comment: How about using `\underbrace`?

Comment: Is this a question about usage on this site? If it is a general MathJax question this site is not the right one to ask about it.

Comment: To add to @quid: it's relatively easy to add a macro for `\underbracket` to your own site but it's hard to do so on math.SE (since it requires deeper hooks into MathJax that `\newcommand` etc do not expose).

Comment: @quid: I wanted to ask on math.stackexchange.com but there is no `mathjax` tag.

Comment: It is good you did not ask on math.stackexchange.com, as it would be very off topic there. If anything you might ask it on Stack Overflow, which has MathJax tag http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathjax I am not certain about this though. Maybe @PeterKrautzberger knows.

Comment: [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) has a MathJax tag; that's probably the best place to ask this.

Comment: @DylanSp no it's not. MathJax is by and large off-topic on [tex.se] site.

Comment: @quid: Per the [mathjax tag wiki](http://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/mathjax/info) on TeX.SE, and the linked meta post(s), I believe this specific type of question (i.e. how to achieve something using the limited subset of (La)TeX available in MathJax) would be considered marginally on-topic there. Questions about installing and configuring MathJax on a website would be off-topic, however.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I do not claim expertise on the OT of that site yet these three recent examples seem somewhat like the question here; [closed1](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288659/how-to-draw-straight-line-cross-element-showing-determinant-calculation), [closed2](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298172/command-for-and-in-mathmode), [closed3](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276872/how-to-type-this-arrow-is-mathstack-exchange) (Meybe the second is a bit different, but still.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it on math.SE via the command:

```
\mathop{\underset{\mmlToken{mo}{⎵}}{78\,255\,300,00}}\limits_{10\text{ zählende Ziffern}}
```

which produces

$$\mathop{\underset{\mmlToken{mo}{⎵}}{78\,255\,300,00}}\limits_{10\text{ zählende Ziffern}}$$

though the vertical spacing is somewhat wider than you probably want.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Second example is then: $$ \mathop{\text{0,000} \underset{\mmlToken{mo}{⎵}}{420800}}\limits_{\text{ 6 zählende Ziffern}} $$

Comment: I might use `0,000\,\mathop{\underset{\mmlToken{mo}{⎵}}{420\,800}}\limits_{\hskip-2em 6\text{ zählende Ziffern}\hskip-2em}` to get more like your original instead: $$0,000\,\mathop{\underset{\mmlToken{mo}{⎵}}{420\,800}}\limits_{\hskip-2em 6\text{ zählende Ziffern}\hskip-2em}$$ though this does mean the expression sticks out on the right.  That may or may not be a problem.